# at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zzai(Unknown Source)

Tags: android

I try to create an app, to open my Google Drive, but i got an error. I have tried with a couple of solutions that i found on the internet but it won't work. Firstly i tried to change a couple of versions at the gradle. Except 9.0.2, i've tried with 9.0.0 ,8.3.0, 8.4.0 .

Code:

```
public class OpenGoogleDrive extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
 {

    private static final String TAG = String.valueOf(1) ;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 1;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_google_drive);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();



    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html" })
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //Log.e("Connected failed", String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onResult(People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {

    }*/
}

Gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'android'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/MARJAN-IT/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'

        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.marjan_it.upnotes"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.0.2'


    //compile 'com.google.gdata.client.contacts.ContactsService'
    compile group: 'com.google.gdata', name: 'core', version: '1.47.1'
    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive
    //compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-drive', version: 'v2-rev65-1.13.2-beta'
}



Error: 

06-21 15:02:29.487 9494-9494/com.example.marjan_it.upnotes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zzai(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.zzu.zzoO(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod$zzc.zzrX(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod$zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpu.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)


Can you help me?
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer. But I have faced same problem and resolved by using just adding one attribute i.e addScope() while building GoogleApiClient

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)


.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.build();
```